# No property id found for type Department

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

> I use @Id in my entity class but I don't know how I get this type of
> issue
> My requirement is insert data into database through postman. But I am
> not able to do that properly
> No property id found for type Department
> I use JPA and MySql for database

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type Department!

> Department.kt

```
 package com.microtrain.departmentservice.entity
    
    import javax.persistence.Entity
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType
    import javax.persistence.Id
    
    
    @Entity
    data class Department(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        val departmentId:Long=-1,
        val departmentName:String="",
        val departmentAddress:String="",
        val departmentCode:String=""
    )
```

> ReqDepartment.kt

```
   data class ReqDepartment (
        val departmentName:String="",
        val departmentAddress:String="",
        val departmentCode:String=""
            )
```

> DepartmetRepositorty.kt

```
package com.microtrain.departmentservice.repository

import com.microtrain.departmentservice.entity.Department
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
interface DepartmentRepository : JpaRepository<Department,Long> {
     fun findDepartmentById(departmentId: Long): Department
}
```

> DepartmentController.kt

```
package com.microtrain.departmentservice.controller

import com.microtrain.departmentservice.entity.Department
import com.microtrain.departmentservice.model.request.ReqDepartment
import com.microtrain.departmentservice.model.response.ResDepartment
import com.microtrain.departmentservice.model.response.ResMessage
import com.microtrain.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository
import com.microtrain.departmentservice.service.DepartmentService
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/departments")
class DepartmentController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var departmentRepository: DepartmentRepository
   
    @PostMapping("/")
   fun departmentRegistration(@ModelAttribute request:ReqDepartment):ResponseEntity<*>{
       val newDepartment= Department(departmentName = request.departmentName,
           departmentAddress = request.departmentAddress,
       departmentCode = request.departmentCode)
        departmentRepository.save(newDepartment)
        val resDepartment=ResDepartment(
            newDepartment.departmentName,
            newDepartment.departmentAddress,
            newDepartment.departmentCode
        )
        return ResponseEntity(resDepartment,HttpStatus.OK)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your repository's query should indicate the correct property name:

```
@Repository
interface DepartmentRepository : JpaRepository<Department,Long> {
    fun findDepartmentByDepartmentId(departmentId: Long): Department
}
```

However, the JpaRepository already offers a `findById(ID id)` method, so there is no need to create an additional query for that yourself.

Comment: If I am not use external query it show me an other compile time error Required:Department  and found:Optional<Department>

Comment: yeah the built-in method returns an optional (empty in case no entity with that ID was found) - you might e.g. just call .get() to access the result